# What are the smallest and biggest negative floating point numbers in IEEE 754 32 bit?

Tags: computer-architecture, floating-point

I am stuck with a question that asks for smallest and biggest negative floating point numbers in **IEEE 754** 32-bit (their representation and decimal numerical value from which one can approximate the precision of the number)? So -0, NaN and Infinity do not belong to negative rational numbers.

I have stumbled upon -3.403 x 10^38 and 2^-126. I came close to the first one actually. I tried to do some calculations but got kind of lost in the process as floating point representation is counter-intutive for me, especially when calculating negative numbers. Can someone help me to clarify my thought process for the calculations so that I can find the numbers?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Look at the definition, then check what the largest possible exponent and mantissa are, and what the smallest possible exponent and mantissa are.